# PHP same random number for all the connected clients

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, timer

Good day everyone, I'm currently struggling with a problem.. I'm trying to think on an effective way to display a random number which will be displayed the same for all the connected clients every 120 seconds.

So far I've implemented a way to retrieve the needed time until the next 120 secs:

```
<?php
   $timestamp = time();
   $nextTwoMinute = ceil($timestamp/120) * 120;
   echo json_encode(($nextTwoMinute - $timestamp));
?>
```

retrieve that with JS and decrement every second after it's loaded:

```
var add_secs = " s";
var time_s = setInterval(update_time, 1000);

function reqListener () {
    console.log(this.responseText);
}
var currTime = "";
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); //New request object
oReq.onload = function() {
    currTime = this.responseText;
};
oReq.open("get", "scripts/php/calc.inc.php", true);
oReq.send();
function update_time() {
    document.getElementById("time_left").value = currTime<0 ? currTime=120:currTime--;
    $("input.circle").val(currTime);
    $("input.circle").trigger('change');
}
```

I want it so after the timer reaches 0 launch an event that'll generate a random number, that number should be the same for every other client. Could this possible be achievable using only PHP, MySQL or JS?

Thank you for reading this topic.

Comment: you have to use cron to update the database and then retrieve data and show it to the users

Comment: so making a simple random function and executing it with cron should fix it? if so thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

**This should solve your issue in php**

```
timestamp=time();
  if($timestamp % 120 == 0)
       //update the random number
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting, however that's not quite what I'm looking for. I can call the event, I just don't know how to make it, as calling the random() function will generate a different random number for every client, I want to generate just one random number and display it to all the clients.